# File uploading with Express 4 using multer in a MVC model example?

Tags: express, multer

I am try to upload a file using express 4 and multer in an MVC framework but it isn't work. 
Is there some working example with a similar use-case ?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are there any errors? Share your code

Comment: Here is my related question regarding the error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272633/node-js-typeerror-cannot-read-property-path-of-undefined.

Also, I am referring this example from this [book](https://github.com/twang281314/frontEnd/blob/master/book/Web%20Development%20with%20MongoDB%20and%20NodeJS%2C%202nd%20Edition.pdf)